# SQL Server MERGE AND UPDATE statemens

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query that uses `MERGE` and `UPDATE` but both return an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

`MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE HRIS_EMPMASTER as T
USING (SELECT DISTINCT
           IDNum, RemarksCode ,AttnmentCode,
           MprNo, DFPCode, CV,GuarID,
           GuarID2, HireFlag 
       FROM VIEW_ADMISSIONLATEST) AS S ON T.HEMP_NO = S.IDNum 

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET [HMSTATUS] = CV,
            [HATTNEMENTCODE] = AttnmentCode,
            [HMPRNO] = MprNo,
            [HGUAR1] = GuarID,
            [HGUAR2] = GuarID2,
            [HDFP_CODE] = DFPCode,
            HHIRE_TYPE = HireFlag;
```

`UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Table_A 
SET Table_A.HREMARKS = Table_B.RemarksCode,
    Table_A.HATTNEMENTCODE = Table_B.AttnmentCode,
    Table_A.HMPRNO=Table_B.MprNo,
    Table_A.HDFP_CODE=Table_B.DFPCode,
    Table_A.HMSTATUS=Table_B.CV,
    Table_A.HGUAR1=Table_B.GuarID,
    Table_A.HGUAR2=Table_B.GuarID2,
    Table_A.HHIRE_TYPE=Table_B.HireFlag
FROM
    HRIS_EMPMASTER AS Table_A
INNER JOIN 
    VIEW_ADMISSIONLATEST AS Table_B ON Table_A.HEMP_NO = Table_B.IDNum
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am stuck by this problem. I have check all the records of my table and there is no duplicate records, but I am stuck with this error always. Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the `select distinct` subquery returning more than one record.

Comment: hmmm i think it's not cause i look on the view there is no duplicate record

Comment: Is there a subquery in the view?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDNum
             ORDER BY ProcessDate DESC) AS rn, IDNum, ProcessDate, RemarksCode, AttnmentCode, MprNo, DFPCode, CAST(CivilStatusCode AS int) AS CV, GuarID, GuarID2, HireFlag
FROM   HRDRecruitment.dbo.Admission) AS src
WHERE rn = 1 . is this what you mean?

Comment: Check `SELECT HEMP_NO, COUNT(*) FROM HRIS_EMPMASTER GROUP BY HEMP_NO HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and same query on the view.

Comment: yes we have already checked that and no duplication.

Comment: Is there a poorly written trigger attached to the updated table?

Comment: Actually, what you want to check for are more than 1 record per unique **IDNum** `SELECT IDNum, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
           IDNum, RemarksCode ,AttnmentCode,
           MprNo, DFPCode, CV,GuarID,
           GuarID2, HireFlag 
       FROM VIEW_ADMISSIONLATEST) g GROUP BY IDNum HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: SMor, thank you. Yeah it is because of the trigger of the table.